# Exit my own thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok I have the following code below

```
public static void StartDayProcessor(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                long lastSec = 0;
                while(DayProcessor.isDayProcessorActive){
                    long sec = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                    if (sec != lastSec) {
                        DayProcessor.secondsActive++;
                        DayProcessor.timeLeftInSecs = DayProcessor.day.getTimeLimitInSecs() - DayProcessor.secondsActive;
                        System.out.println("Seconds left for this day: " + DayProcessor.timeLeftInSecs);
                        if(DayProcessor.timeLeftInSecs == 0){
                            DayProcessor.isDayProcessorActive = false;
                            break;
                            //exit my own thread here!!
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

That code above is inside of my more bigger code, but what I want to know is how can I stop the thread on running by running a code inside the thread itself. How can I stop it?

Comment: The thread automatically exits after executing the code in the run function. You need not explicitly stop it

Comment: Your code *already* stops the thread

Comment: @Bohemian really???!! how can I know it? I am using eclipse

Comment: thank you!! its already working at it is XD

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to stop a thread, one you already using via conditional logic and `break`/`return`:

```
DayProcessor.isDayProcessorActive = false;
break;//return;
```

Other way is to use `interrupt`:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
     ... logic
     if(condition) {
         Thread.interrupt();
     }
}
```

Comment: Interrupt doesn't stop the thread. It just sets the interrupt flag and raises an interrupted exception. If the running code catches the exception it may ignore it and continue

Comment: yes, it doesn't stop the thread. but we use it to signal a condition and handles to abort/cancel a thread (it just a in-built means not a direct way)

Answer (score 0):

You ca use return .

And if you want to return your Thread on a specific condition,you can have a global variable amd set it value as true when you want to return your Thread and in your Thread check the value of variable and just call return.

It can help you control your Thread even from your main Thread where you can set the value of variable as true.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void StartDayProcessor(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                long lastSec = 0;
            LabeledLoop:
                while(DayProcessor.isDayProcessorActive){
                    long sec = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                    if (sec != lastSec) {
                        DayProcessor.secondsActive++;
                        DayProcessor.timeLeftInSecs = DayProcessor.day.getTimeLimitInSecs() - DayProcessor.secondsActive;
                        System.out.println("Seconds left for this day: " + DayProcessor.timeLeftInSecs);
                        if(DayProcessor.timeLeftInSecs == 0){
                            DayProcessor.isDayProcessorActive = false;
                            break LabeledLoop;
                            //exit my own thread here!!
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

**By breaking the loop, the Thread should stop on it's own.**

Answer (score 0):

Common ways to stop a thread including

- Having the thread run() method auto quit when finished execution.
- Check a state variable which can be set from outside of the thread. Since this is a typical 1 thread reading the other writing scenario, volatile should be used.

I won't suggest to interrupt a thread because that implies the thread isn't terminated gracefully and resources might remain uncleaned.